# Limit number of results from array_agg

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I'm struggling with limiting the number of results returned from `array_agg()`. This is my query so far:

```
SELECT s.*,
(
  SELECT array_agg(row_to_json(smr.*))
  AS "monthRatings"
)
FROM services s
INNER JOIN servicemonthratings smr ON s._id = smr.service_id
GROUP BY s._id
```

Is there maybe a better way to accomplish the same thing as above?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Your question is not clear.

Comment: Do you really want a Postgres array of json values? Not a JSON array? And do you really want an `INNER JOIN` eliminating services that have not ratings (yet)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpler:

```
SELECT s.*, array_agg(row_to_json(smr)) AS "monthRatings"
FROM   services s
JOIN   servicemonthratings smr ON s._id = smr.service_id
GROUP  BY s._id;
```

- No need for a subselect.
- You can just use the table alias `smr` (meaning the row type) instead of `smr.*`, same result here.
- `services._id` must be the PK, or the query is nonsense.

I suspect you really want a JSON array of rows, and you don't want to eliminate services that have no ratings (yet):

```
SELECT s.*, smr."monthRatings"
FROM   services s, LATERAL (
   SELECT json_agg(smr) AS "monthRatings"
   FROM   servicemonthratings smr
   WHERE  smr.service_id = s._id
   ) smr;
```

Now you don't need to aggregate `services`, and `_id` does not have to be the PK.

And since this `LATERAL` subquery *always* returns a row (due to the aggregate function in it) no services are eliminated.

Comment: Hey Erwin. I think the second query should be `SELECT json_agg(smr) AS "monthRatings" FROM   servicemonthratings smr` otherwise json_agg don't know what is smr.

Comment: @jian Yes, the table alias was missing, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

That doesn't make sense you're clearly confused.

1. You don't use array_agg to aggregate json. You use json_agg.
2. If you're going to use array_agg() like that, you may as well use the array constructor `ARRAY()`
3. If you're going to use array_agg, you should roll it into the outer and get it out of the array list.

Put up some sample data and your desired output.